Filtering AG grid master detail (across main and detailed grids) angular
I am trying to mimic the working example found in the example here with the latest APIs of AG grid (latest version to date), I'm not able to figure out what is wrong and why the filter doesn't work
Here is the link to my code I'm trying and the one I referred to is Here
The differences I could see are the value updated by Input and I believe it shouldn't make much difference but this below piece of code that new API is being used to set quickFilter
Previous versions
  onInputChanged(toFilterBy) {
    console.log(this.gridApi, toFilterBy);
    this.gridApi.setQuickFilter(toFilterBy); // this

    this.gridApi.forEachDetailGridInfo((detailGridInfo) => {
      detailGridInfo.api.setQuickFilter(toFilterBy);  // and this
    });
  }


Newer version API
onInputChanged() {
    const toFilterBy = (document.getElementById('filter-text') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    console.log(this.gridApi, toFilterBy);
    this.gridApi.setGridOption('quickFilterText', toFilterBy);

    this.gridApi.forEachDetailGridInfo((detailGridInfo) => {
      detailGridInfo.api.setGridOption('quickFilterText', toFilterBy);
    });
  }

I'm not sure what is missed or did incorrectly, any help or a guide would be appreciated. Thanks

Not sure what someone made to vote down , atleast would have mentioned what is not clear ... honestly the docs are great but with no such examples and outdated api examples found somewhere are pain in the a** ...

OMG finally figured out what I was missing ...
In docs it mentioned "Include Hidden Columns" that is
setGridOption('includeHiddenColumnsInQuickFilter', true)

Since we are storing the detail grid as a string value in to the new column
// this column must be added to be included in the quick filter
{ field: 'searchableOrDetailRows', hide: true },

Which was a great technique to filter deep, now the thing is it was hidden  and until we set the gridOption mentioned above it doesn't include ..
What a silly thing to miss out ... Hope it helps some one in future, updated the plunker link here for ref
